# Select2 + custom scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscrollpane, jquery-select2, nicescroll

I'm trying to connect some custom scrollbars with Select2 4.0. I found some old topics here on stackoverflow, but the solutions (with select2 3.4 i.e.) seems to be outdated.

I tried: jquery.scrollpane and jquery.nicescroll. Both scrollbars don't work with Select2 4.0. Or maybe I did something wrong?

scrollpane solution (when used, "No results found" error occures)

```js
$(function() {
 $('.select2-with-scroll').jScrollPane();
 
 $w.on('resize', function() {
  $('.select2-with-scroll').jScrollPane();
 });
});
```

```html
<select class="select2-with-scroll">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="50">50</option>
  <option value="55">55</option>
  <option value="60">60</option>
  <option value="65">65</option>
  <option value="70">70</option>
  <option value="75">75</option>
  <option value="80">80</option>
  <option value="85">85</option>
  <option value="90">90</option>
  <option value="95">95</option>
  <option value="100">100</option>
</select>
```

nicescroll solution (absolutely no effects, HTML as above)

```js
$(document).ready(
  function() { 
    $("select2-with-scroll").niceScroll();
  }
);
```

Is there any other custom scrollbars which I can use with Select2 4.0? Or maybe it's possible to connect nicescroll or scrollpane with Select2? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

With **select2 v4.0** + **nicescroll v3.6.6** try to make something like this

```
$('select').select2()
.on("select2:open", function () {
    $('.select2-results__options').niceScroll();
});
```